# Getting the connection string from nHibernate returns the string WITHOUT the password

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate

I need to directly access the database on a nhibernate application. I am trying to get the connection string like this:

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.session.Connection.ConnectionString))
```

But this will return the connection string WITHOUT the password.

I'm I doing something wrong? Is there any other way to get the connection string?

Comment: Why don't you just use that connection?

Comment: I really prefer not use the same connection as nhibernate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain a raw database connection (using the same connection details as NHibernate) from the NHibernate SessionFactory, e.g.:

> IDbConnection connection =
>   yourSessionFactory.ConnectionProvider.GetConnection()

Comment: In other words, you don't need the connection string. Note that it is not NHibernate that is suppressing the password, but ADO.NET - so you can't really do much about it...its a security feature.

Comment: Pretty stupid of ADO.NET to suppress the password as I can parse the configuration file and get it by myself.

Comment: ADO.NET doesn't know where you get your connectstring from.

Comment: You will also need to cast the `SessionFactory` to the concrete implementation `(NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl)` in order to access the `ConnectionProvider` property (at least in NH v3).

Comment: I Downvoted because the answer doesn't show how to obtain the plain connectionString with password. You can get the connection from the session also.

Answer (score 2):

```
ISessionFactory SessionFactory = (NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl)session.SessionFactory;//ISession session
        Type typeOfConnectionProvider = typeof(NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider);
        PropertyInfo ConnectionStringPropertyInfo = typeOfConnectionProvider.GetProperty("ConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        string connectionString = (string)ConnectionStringPropertyInfo.GetValue(((NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider)((NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl)SessionFactory).ConnectionProvider), null);
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on what the code does?  Just posting the code, while it may solve the problem, does not really help things for someone searching this question in the future.

Comment: It will be highly expected and appreciated if explanation of your answer will added.